# On device text detection with react-native-firebase asks for billing

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am using react-native-firebase-mlkit vision to process images taken from the camera (using react-native-camera). Text detection is requiring for billling but the firebase documentation says the on device detection is free. 
Here is the snippet I am using

```
  processImage = async () => {
    const {photoUri} = this.state;
    console.log('processing Image...');
    vision()
      .cloudTextRecognizerProcessImage(photoUri)
      .then(processed => {
        console.log('processImage response', processed);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('process error', error);
      });
  };
```

Here is the error
[image: Error on detection]

How can I activate on device detection with react-native-firebase-mlkit vision ?

Comment: Ok I've figured this out: I have to use  the `textRecognizerProcessImage()` function instead of `cloudTextRecognizerProcessImage()`. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've figured this out.
For **on device detection** with react-native-firebase-mlkit vision you have to use  the `textRecognizerProcessImage()` function instead of `cloudTextRecognizerProcessImage()`

```
  processImage = async () => {
    const {photoUri} = this.state;
    console.log('processing Image...');
    vision()
      .textRecognizerProcessImage(photoUri)
      .then(processed => {
        console.log('processImage response', processed);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('process error', error);
      });
  };
```